# Google maps api v3 in the manifest

Tags: iphone, android, web-applications, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to caching in a manifest file the entire Google Maps Api for an offline ( mobile ) use ?

I don'want the maps images, because i will use an overlay map so, the aim is to use the functionality ( GPS detection, pinch to zoom, marker ecc.. ) but with MY MAP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that is possible.  You should look at alternative mapping libraries like osmdroid: http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have found this javascript library that can works offline:

http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/

I have tried to set a single tile ( like a grey PNG ) and add a image layer ( My map ). It works fine without connection , but it have some problems with Android devices ( The overlay map is not displayed ), and the overlay image don't zoom with the gesture, i mean that the image zoom, when the gesture end, users don't have any feedback on how much zoom it will be applicated.